# How to add checkbox in ng2-table in Angular-4?

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, ng2-smart-table

I need to add checkbox in Angular 4 typescript we are using ng2-table.

```
//code for ng-table in html
<ng-table (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)"
(cellClicked)="onCellClick($event)"
[rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
</ng-table>

//to create checkbox I am adding html in component where filling the data.
data.forEach((item: any) => 
{item.CheckBox = '<input type="checkbox"></input>';

//cell click event in table component is getting triggered
public onCellClick(data: any): any {
     this event is getting triggered
     ....
}
```

1. Check box on UI is disabled or not able to checked. 
   I think some event is getting triggered and reverting selected value to false 
   each time. How to prevent that?
2. Where do I bind this check box to ng-model or similar?

Please help. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your data binded to the table? Where is the template for the checkbox? Can you re-create your problem in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular) repo?

By the way, there is a thread about checkboxes in the [official repo issues](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/issues/444)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not regular check box. It is contained in ng2-table. I am able to trigger cell-click event. But check box is disabled from UI. Also going through the links you provided.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? In [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) for instance.

Comment: I have edited my question and added more details. If you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Problem is solved. In cellClick event we are able to add dynamic basic html code. Which has solved the problem.